# How do I close a browser tab after running Python?

Tags: javascript, python, django

I have a web application where I need to open a new tab, run some Python, then close the tab. The reason I'm doing it this way rather than redirecting to the previous page is because the users would like it to retain the search filters.

I'm using Firefox to test it, and I'm aware that Javascript won't close the window if it wasn't opened with Javascript; apparently the same is true if I run any Python functions, because the "cancel" button on the same tab works without any problems.

Things I have tried:

1. using HttpResponseRedirect to redirect to a new page with a "close" button that runs a Javascript function to close - the function is definitely being called (I can prove this with a window.alert) but the "window.close()" line gets ignored (no errors or anything, it simply does nothing).
2. using HttpResponse to return 'window.close()' in the Python code - again, if I change it to a window.alert, I can prove the script is running, but again, the 'window.close()' is completely ignored.
3. adding a window.close() function to the Submit button - this only works if I run it before the "submit", in which case the tab will close, but the "submit" will not happen.

Is there any workaround for this? Making users manually close the new tab with the X button just feels like such an obnoxious way to do it, and this feels like it should be so simple to do.

Comment: `The reason I'm doing it this way rather than redirecting to the previous page is because the users would like it to retain the search filters.` I'm very sure you are not thinking your issue through correctly. Use GET params in the URL to retain search filters. This is the normal way to accomplish what you are wanting in terms of the statement above.

Comment: From the source page, you can do a `window.open()` for the new page and then have the page post a form or something to load the actual content. If you do that, then `window.close()` on the new tab/window will work.

Comment: @ViaTech thanks... I'd like to do it that way but not sure how...
The hyperlink to open the page is: 
'''<a href="{ url 'Name' _param1 _param2 %}>'''
And the existing GET method is:
'''def get(self, request, _param1, _param2)'''
Obviously the URL to the page contains the two parameters. There is also a POST method:
'''def post(self, request, _param1, _param2)'''
which returns the user to the original page:
'''_urlName = "Name" + _param2 + "Search"'''
So I need to pass the previous URL from the GET to the _urlName in the POST. How do I do that? (I'm new to Python)

Comment: @Pointy thanks, this method worked! I was using "target=_blank" in the href to open it, which wouldn't let me close it that way after the Python redirect, but using Javascript to run "window.open()" does. I realise this isn't the correct way to do what I want but it's the only method I could make work with what I had.